# When removing Ensembles, can the current data be restored to the CoreData store?

Tags: ensembles

If a user decides he/she doesn't want to use syncing anymore (for whatever reason), is there a way to have the app (or Ensembles) to restore the original CoreData store to it's current state from the changes in iCloud?  I looked in the "book" but didn't find anything... oh, and I'm using MagicalRecord.  :D

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. If you have ensembles syncing, and the user decides to turn it off, you don't have to do anything. Just keep using the core data store with the data in it. That is one of the nice things about ensembles — your CD stack is unchanged.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you.. SD